# Error Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest' : Refused to connect 'http://192.168.XX.XXX:8080/TestApp/addRole/ : Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Facing error while calling rest api in ionic.
If I run on browser firefox or chrome then it working fine..
But When I run On android device then it gives following error:

```
Error: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Refused to connectto 'http://192.168.XX.XXX:8080/TestApp/addRole/' becuase it violates the document's content security Policy
at Error (native( at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:23357:16
```

How can I solve this issue

If I set following meta tag in index.html as follow then got error in chrome and android device..Not in firefox

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

On my rest service i set header as follow

> responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
>           responseHeaders.add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type");

I also install whitelist plugin but no luck

How can I solve this issue? please help

Comment: Your CSP field in the manifest should look something like this: **"content_security_policy": "default-src 'self' https://google.com"**

Comment: Thanks for your reply can you please elaborate this,,

Comment: ok do you have **CROS** extenstion in your google chrome

Comment: yes i have in chrome..problem is not working in device only

Comment: i think you are not running your project in your local host

Comment: please refer this blog https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/05/whitelist-external-resources-for-use-in-ionic-framework/ for white list plgin issues

Comment: I am running on my localhost..In mob if i check myip:8080 then server its working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109898/discussion-between-mohan-gopi-and-user3855589).

Answer (score 3):

On Android you need to set a content-security-policy meta tag in your `<head>` @ index.html.

It would look something like this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline' data: gap: 'unsafe-eval'; style-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; connect-src * ; script-src * 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

In this occasion there is a lot of unsafe and unnecessary tags which allow almost anything but you can read more about them for example in here:

[Cordova whitelist plugin content security policy](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/#content-security-policy)

In the same page there are also explanations for other stuff like network request whitelist.

Hopefully this gets you through your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my security policy declaration meta on Cordova.. worked for me after 2 days of heavy wandering around the web:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval' *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *; img-src * data: content:;">
```

I simply added a wildcard at the default-src, inner attribute end.. and definitely am going to develop an above security layer on all of my app inputs, cause it looks like an all access to me.

Saved my day.. hope someone's day too